# How to use Bloc with Flutter Navigation?

Tags: flutter, bloc

I am quite new to flutter and even newer to Bloc pattern. I am building a music player app to get a better grasp of the basic concepts of bloc. What I want to know is that should we actually use navigation with Bloc patter or simply display everything on the same page.

Eg: I have a page with a grid view of playlists and the playlists name and album art and stuff are supplied by a bloc(**playlist_provider_bloc**). I also have a separate bloc for providing the songs list(**song_provider_bloc**) and stream url and stuff in another bloc. Now here are a few ways I have thought about:

1. Simply creating a separate instance of **song_provider_bloc** for every playlist and pass that instance when pushing the page for displaying songs.
2. Use a single instance of **song_provider_bloc** and keeping the name of the playlist in the **song_provider_state** so as to check if the currently open playlist is changed.
3. Do not use navigation. Just update a single page for both playlist and song list.

So which approach is the best one among the following?

Comment: The related questions displayed on right will provide you with the information you need, and maybe more.

Comment: for helping you take a look at this andriod only plugin https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_audio_query